# Do frameset work in quirks mode (IE9 - IE10)?

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, frameset

I am working a very old application which is used in quirks mode - IE7. It is working with frames (frameset).

Do those frames will work (no effects) with IE9 - IE10 by staying in the quirks mode (no doctype)? Is it possible to be still running under IE9 - IE10 ?

==> EDIT
Frameset are obsolete in html5, does it mean the same in quirks mode (no DTD) for IE9 - IE10 ?

Comment: did you test this yourself? What tests have you ran?

Comment: sounds it works, but do frameset are obsolete in html5, does it mean the same in quirks mode (no DTD) ?

Comment: Nobody said all that modern browsers could display was HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

I guess adding in IE10 or IE9

```
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5">
```

make frameset work as in IE7-

Natively, IE9 can support frameset but IE10 no more

Comment: Yea I tried, but as expected the CSS file didnt work anymore. I wanted to add     <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd"> ... but same result

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing. My IE10 loads a frameset without complaining. And why wouldn't it? It's not that everybody magically stopped using frames. - Can you provide an example that does not work?

Comment: When I say frameset dont work in IE10, I mean JS interactions, for instance : parent.frames(target) returns undefined if you dont add the quirks IE5 tag in the DoM Head

Comment: As I said - can you provide an example that does not work for you? BTW, next time such information should be part of the question, not part of the 4th comment under some answer.